# Why are comments being removed without trace or notification?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are a lot of comments being deleted on this SE?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/400/are-a-lot-of-comments-being-deleted-on-this-se)

I am becoming frustrated at the continued removal of comments I have made, without any notification to me or notice that they were removed. Seemingly for seemingly no good reason.

Some examples would be [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/does-this-site-need-firmer-guidelines%20https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/do-claims-on-this-site-need-to-be-explicit) where my comments in reply to Oddthinkings post were removed and [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/do-claims-on-this-site-need-to-be-explicit) where my comments in reply to Sklivvz and Borror0 were removed.

I understand comments may sometimes get to long or contain insults so may need to be removed.

However when I reply to a comment which is discussing an answer to a question, without it being offtopic or insulting or such there would seem little basis for it to be removed.

Several comments I have made to issues I raised on meta are continually removed. I received no warning or even notification that comments were removed or were inappropriate.

My understanding is that if comments were abusive or inappropriate a warning would be given, or if comments were too long they would be removed with a message saying as much. For comments to simply disappear repeatedly is...odd.

Given that my comments only stated an opinion, were on topic and did not contain insults or have any other seemingly obvious reason for removal, I can only guess it was due to a moderator disagreeing with them.

I would like for this to stop. It is frustrating to express an opinion only to have it disappear without a trace for no reason. It is certainly not a way to encourage new users to the site and as I don't encounter this behavior on other SE sites I can't see it as being a standard policy.

Comment: Without examples of posts where your comments were removed, we can only guess. If you have a few questions or answers in mind, please post them so I can take a closer look.

Comment: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/does-this-site-need-firmer-guidelines : My comments in reply to Oddthinking's post were removed several times, silently. http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/do-claims-on-this-site-need-to-be-explicit My comments in reply to your answer and Sklivvz's answer were removed silently. Just some examples.

Comment: In each of those cases, a comment was left explaining the reasoning.

Comment: I never saw such a comment. Even checking that page now, I don't see such a comment. I would like to read if if they are still there, as I would like to see the reasoning.

Comment: The irony here is just too much.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell: About the first example: a comment explaining the reasoning was left on November 22nd and deleted by Sklivvz on November 26th. Between that time span, you logged on Meta.Skeptics on two different days. You should have seen it. About the second example: a comment explaining the reasoning was left on November 25th and deleted by me on December 17th. Between that time span, you logged on Meta.Skeptics on four different days. Again, you should have seen it.

Comment: Simply because I logged on to the site is not enough to say I should have seen it, especially since it is one of many sites that I login automatically to when I open my browser, even though I might check it at all. I guess it's nice to know there was a reason given.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell: Your complaint was that there was no notification. There was. Moreover, the days I mentioned where the ones where you loaded at least one Meta.Skeptics page. If we go network-wide, the number of days where you could have seen the notification is likely to go up substantially.

Comment: @Borror0 I am not disputing that you say there was a notification, I am simply saying I never saw it as it was later removed. The fact that I may be logged as visiting the site does not mean I actually visited the site, as I said it is one of many sites that I have open when my browser starts. I'm sorry if it seemed like I was disputing that a notification was given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We routinely, unashamedly, ruthlessly clean up comments.

Why? Because we do not want the community to engage in extended discussion in them.

If you have something meaningful to say *use a question or an answer*, so people can vote/edit/improve your content!

The comments are meant to be used to provide *constructive* criticism to the content they are attached to. For example: documenting the reason of a vote, or requesting a change are good uses of comments.

In meta. especially, it is bad form to express a dissenting opinion in the comments. If you dissent, put up a separate answer so people can vote up/down based on their agreement.

Not so good usages include *answering other comments*, unless it's a simple clarification (and even then, it should be as limited as possible).

For example, just look at this question:

- Borror0 commented that we need some examples (correct usage)

> Without examples of posts where your comments were removed, we can only guess. If you have a few questions or answers in mind, please post them so I can take a closer look.

- You provided some examples *in a comment* (incorrect, you should have edited your question, and Borror0 or another mod would have removed the initial comment).

> https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/does-this-site-need-firmer-guidelines : My comments in reply to Oddthinking's post were removed several times, silently. [Do claims on this site need to be explicit?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/do-claims-on-this-site-need-to-be-explicit) My comments in reply to your answer and Sklivvz's answer were removed silently. Just some examples.

- Borror0 then answered that a comment was left (incorrect, he should have posted an answer. I think he left a comment because he thought you were going to provide a better example, which would have made his answer obsolete).

> In each of those cases, a comment was left explaining the reasoning.

- You did not provide a better example, but you engaged in further discussion (incorrect).

> I never saw such a comment. Even checking that page now, I don't see such a comment. I would like to read if if they are still there, as I would like to see the reasoning.

At this point, I was *very* tempted to include your examples in your question by editing and burn the whole thread... but somehow I was worried to make you even more upset, so I've avoided that.

In other words: **Stack exchange sites are not forums.** We care about **questions** and **answers**. *Comments are for temporary content and not discussion.*

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I will edit the question and have no problem with comments being removed. The main problem I had was when my comments kept being removed and I didn't see a notification (Borror0 said there was one which was later removed).

Comment: You know, I commented on one of your posts where you stated that something would be _funny_, but in fact is not perceived funny by most suffereres of the thing in question. This was intended as an opportunity to improve your answer, yet you silently removed the comment without further notice, not editing the answer in question. By your definition, that was inconsequent. In my definition, this is arrogant and ignorant.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed many meta-questions ask important questions but really boil down to "why was my question closed?" I'm going to ignore this latter issue (which Borror0 has addressed in the comments) and stick to the big question.

> My understanding is that if comments were abusive or inappropriate a warning would be given, or if comments were too long they would be removed with a message saying as much.

The direction that we have (publicly) received from our "Stack OverLords" at StackExchange Inc. is that the StackExchange sites are focussed on Questions and Answers. Comments are a form of second-class citizen. Unlike other forums, the goal is not to promote discussion - it is to record good answers to quality questions.

Some examples:

- [Should comments enjoy the same protection as other posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119068/should-comments-enjoy-the-same-protection-as-other-posts)
- [Is the official comment policy obsolete, and should we change it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104981/is-the-official-comment-policy-obsolete-and-should-we-change-it)
- Extended discussion is automatically sent to chat.
- You need more rep to comment than ask or answer.

(It wouldn't be a Meta-StackExchange without a counter-example: [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work))

I see comments as a mechanism to achieve the goal of good Q&A goal, but their are not a goal in themselves.

They are, routinely, deleted without notice or apology. Reasons include: spam, noise (including not adding to the discussion), offensiveness, being obsolete, being clearly wrong, being flagged, being part of a large discussion that is distracting from the question (Mea culpa!).

Notice is often given, especially if it will prevent a repeat, but sometimes it doesn't add much value to replace a distracting comment with a distracting comment.